# How to modify an element of array in file.json using Python?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord.py giveaway bot

and in that I trying to save the status (ongoing or ended) of the giveaway.

but I don't know how to modify the array

here's the code:-

```
  with open ('gw.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    new_gw = {
      'gw_id': f"{react.id}",
      'gw_prize': prize,
      'gw_status': "ongoing"
    }

  data.append(new_gw)

  with open('gw.json', 'w') as j:
    json.dump(data, j, indent=3)
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work

```
with open('gw.json') as gw_file:
      data = json.load(gw_file)
      for x in data:
        if x['gw_id'] == msgid:
          x['gw_status'] = "ended"

  with open('gw.json', 'w') as j:
    json.dump(data, j)
```

tried googling it too but nothing worked for me

what I want to do is change 'gw_status' from ongoing to ended
from:-

```
[
   {
      "gw_id": "904772439827951657",
      "gw_prize": "4",
      "gw_status": "ongoing"
   }
]
```

to this:-

````
[
   {
      "gw_id": "904772439827951657",
      "gw_prize": "4",
      "gw_status": "ended"
   }
]
``` on the existing entry that was added before
````

Comment: Hey, you can remove the part that's not relevant to the problem. If you can provide the reproducible code, it'll be easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it correctly adds a new entry to the JSON and changes the gw_status for a specific id.
Tested with Python 3.7.4.

Comment: so then how to change the status of a existing entry

Comment: i want to change the existing entries 'gw_status' = "ended"

Comment: It should change all existing entries because the whole json file is opened again and all entries are checked for the winner.